# How to hook into user authentication?

Tags: 8

I have a 2FA option users can enable. I am currently writing an API layer where I want to preserve this functionality. So far, I haven't been able to hook into authentication. `\Drupal\user\UserAuth` doesn't invoke any hook or event.

Is replacing the *user.auth* service with a custom implementation the only solution?

Comment: Swapping the core user auth I believe is the way to go. I recently implemented SSO for the same reason you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. Create a service provider in your custom module that extends ServiceProviderBase.  The name of this class must be your module name, in camel case, with *ServiceProvider* appended. The class must implements `alter()`, which changes the class for the *user.auth* service.

   ```php
   public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
     $definition = $container->getDefinition('user.auth');
     $definition->setClass('Drupal\my_module\AuthenticationClass');
   }
   ```
2. `Drupal\my_module\AuthenticationClass` needs to extend `\Drupal\user\UserAuth` and define an `authenticate($username, $password)` method, which returns `TRUE` when the authentication is successful.

Comment: Did this work for you @ivan-jaros ?